# EJB query which uses TRUNC and WITH

Tags: java, sql, oracle, ejb, nativequery

I have a query which works fine when I use NativeQuery but I need to use an EJB query for my problem. Can anyone help me reformat my query so it would work for EJB also?

Here is the Native version

```
Query query = getEntityManager.createNativeQuery("WITH src as ("
+ "Select distinct TRUNC(CreationDate) a" 
+ "From myTable)"
+ "Select src.a from src Order by src.a desc");
```

The Class for myTable is an Entity type. The Properties are as followed

```
    @Id
    private Long Id; 

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String Name;

    @Column(length = 30, nullable = false)
    private Timestamp CreationDate;
```

The properties are as above with setters and getters for them. (Except for ID)
Thanks

Comment: I asked about the class name

Comment: What entity provider do you use? Hibernate? EclipseLink? OpenJPA?

Comment: Hibernate, the class name is myTable also

Comment: Did you specify oracle dialect in your hibernate.cfg.xml?

Answer (score 0):

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    TRUNC(CreationDate) as a
        FROM 
            (SELECT CreationDate  FROM myTable ORDER BY CreationDate DESC)
```

---

Comment: This query results in an exception saying 'could not resolve property a'

Comment: No still same error,it looks the same as before though!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Query query = getEntityManager.createQuery(
                "select DISTINCT TRUNC(src.CreationDate) 
                   from myTable src 
                  ORDER by src.CreationDate"
              );
List<Object[]> rows = query.list();
for (Object[] row: rows) {
    System.out.println("My date" + row[0]);
}
```

Comment: It does not work, order by would not work when you are using TRUNC in your select statement. It generates a GrammerException

Comment: What is wrong with `order by`? Get rid it during the debugging process.